# How to open a new tab in a browser by click on SSRS bar chart report

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I have developed some SSRS reports which are I am accessing in a web application dashboard, hosted on JBOSS server. I want to open a new tab on click of bar chart report so far I have used

```
javascript:void(window.open('URL','_blank'))
```

in SSRS Bar Chart Report but it's not working for me. Also, I have tried `&rc:LinkTarget=_blank`  as well but no success yet, the report opening in the same tab only. Browser Inspector shows that `target` property got set to `_top` instead of `_blank`.

```
="java script:void(window.open('URL','_blank'))"
```

In addition to the above, I have tested SSRS report its working fine and opening new tab when running it individually(directly run using web service URL in a browser), but when you accessed this reports in a hosted web application dashboard it's not working.

Could you guys please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the action property. Go on your tablix cell or textbox **Textbox Properties > Action > Go to URL** and add your URL. For example:

```
https://www.google.de/
```

Now when you execute the reort and you click on the cell, you will jump to the site.

Comment: Hi Strawberryshrub, I have already added Action-->URL to the series of a bar chart. In addition to above, SSRS report is running well when you run it individually but when you accessed this report in a hosted web application dashboard it's not working

Comment: Hmm ok, I just use a report server, so I cant help you with that one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. do anybody have faced the same issue, please help me to resolve this. Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: hi, guys waiting for your response.

Comment: Hello guys, waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might be what you are asking for. This is what I use and it works well for me.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('URL & Parameter =" & Fields!Parameter.Value & "&rs:ClearSession=True','NewTabName'))"
```

I am currently trying to figure out a variant of this where it opens the report as a pdf in a new browser tab.